# Snowflake conditional code: adding new column(idempotent script)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

Let's assume we have a table that contains data as below:

```
CREATE TABLE tab(i INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tab(i) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
SELECT * FROM tab;
```

Now my goal is to create SQL script that will add a new column to existing table:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab ADD COLUMN col VARCHAR(10);
```

Everything works as intended. Except the fact I would like to be able to run script multiple times but the effect should take place only once([idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence)).

If I try to run it again I will get:

> *SQL compilation error: column COL already exists*

---

Normally I would use one of these approaches:

a) Using control structure **IF** to check metadata tables before executing query:

```
-- (T-SQL)
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
              WHERE TABLE_NAME='TAB' AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL')
BEGIN
   ALTER TABLE tab ADD col VARCHAR(10);
END;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=00aa56552b80002086d252a3c3e84965)**

I have not found IF statement in Snowflake's documentation.

b) SQL dialect that supports `IF NOT EXISTS` syntax:

```
-- PostgreSQL
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS col VARCHAR(10);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=cf31144678e0162d5b931a26241f5bf1)**

Most of Snowflake SQL commands contain `IF EXISTS`/`OR REPLACE` clauses which means it was written in a way to allow running scripts multiple times.

---

I was considering using code like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab
AS
SELECT i, CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR(10)) AS col
FROM tab;
```

This approach on other hand causes unnecessary table creation and does not preserve metadata(like primary key).

---

Is there a way to achieve similar effect on Snowflake? Preferably by using conditional code(add column is an example).

Comment: I think the only current option is to embed the logic in a stored procedure, which has to be written in JavaScript. Here's a [pretty recent blog post](https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-control-structures-if-do-while-for.html/) on just this topic, though obviously written by a web dev rather than a data dev.

Comment: @EricBrandt Thank you for idea. Yes, embeding that logic with a kind of generic stored procedure is a possible solution. Though I see two drawbacks: 1) polution schema with additional procedures(of course this could be easily resolved with cleanup script so it is not really huge deal) 2) Stored procedures are written in JS(of course it is not also an issue, just it won't be pure SQL script). Please feel free to post it as answer, it deserves an upvote :)

Comment: I expanded on the comment a little to make it feel more worthy of the answer box. :) Glad to have helped!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's in the docs, but this syntax now appears to work:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS col VARCHAR(10);
```

Comment: Nice catch! Exactly the answer I tried in the past but it did not work then but apparently it works with version 7.31.1

Comment: It is now also in the docs. [ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction) - `If you are not sure if the column already exists, you can specify IF NOT EXISTS when adding the column. If the column already exists, ADD COLUMN has no effect on the existing column and does not result in an error.`

Answer (score 6):

You can use something like this. It will report the failure to add the column if it already exists, but it will handle the error so it won't interfere with the execution of a sql script:

```
create or replace procedure SafeAddColumn(tableName string, columnName string, columnType string)
returns string
language JavaScript
as
$$
    var sql_command = "ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLENAME + " ADD COLUMN " + COLUMNNAME + " " + COLUMNTYPE + ";";
    var strOut;
    try {
        var stmt = snowflake.createStatement( {sqlText: sql_command} );
        var resultSet = stmt.execute();
        while (resultSet.next())  {
            strOut = resultSet.getColumnValue(1);
        }
    }
    catch (err)  {
        strOut = "Failed: " + err;   // Return a success/error indicator.
    }
    return strOut;
$$;

CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE tab(i INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tab(i) VALUES(1),(2),(3);
SELECT * FROM tab;

call SafeAddColumn('tab', 'col', 'varchar(10)');
select * from tab;
call SafeAddColumn('tab', 'col', 'varchar(10)');
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer . Yes, that will of course work. From enginering perspective I am not a fan of perfroming an operation, allow it to fail and handle the error(if I could predict the result in advance). My final approach so far is using two subsequent calls (1 - reading information_schema, conditional logic in JS, 2 - ALTER TABLE). I hope one day we will get `IF NOT EXISTS` clause and have full capability to perform it with SQL only :)

Answer (score 6):

It is possible to write conditional code using Snowflake Scripting.

[Working with Branching Constructs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html)

> **Snowflake Scripting** supports the following branching constructs:
>
> - **IF-THEN-ELSEIF-ELSE**
> - **CASE**

Setup:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE PUBLIC.tab(i INT PRIMARY KEY);
INSERT INTO tab(i) VALUES(1),(2);
SELECT * FROM tab;
-- i
-- 1
-- 2
```

Code that can be rerun multiple times(subsequent runs will take no effect):

```
-- Snowsight
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TAB' 
                   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
                   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL')) THEN
    ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab ADD COLUMN col VARCHAR(10);
  END IF;
END;
```

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE is required is run using "classic web interface":

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE $$
BEGIN
  IF (NOT EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TAB' 
                   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC' 
                   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL')) THEN
    ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab ADD COLUMN col VARCHAR(10);
  END IF;
END;
$$
```

After:

```
SELECT * FROM tab;
-- i  col
-- 1  NULL
-- 2  NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

Although Snowflake has implemented a pretty rich mix of DDL and DML for their SQL implementation, when it comes to procedural code they seem to be relying on JavaScript, at least at this point. But you should be able to accomplish your idempotent `ALTER` script through a JavaScript stored procedure.

I'm afraid I lack the JavaScript skills to provide you with a working sample myself at this point. The organization I'm with recently adopted Snowflake, though, so I'll share some of my research.

Here's a recent blog post on just this question:

[Snowflake Control Structures – IF, DO, WHILE, FOR](https://dwgeek.com/snowflake-control-structures-if-do-while-for.html/)

Snowflake's overview documentation regarding stored procedures:

[Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures.html)

On the page above, what is currently the third link down contains extensive sample code.

[Working With Stored Procedures](https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/stored-procedures-usage.html)

Answer (score 1):

Building on Lukasz answer, to include database in condition you can use:

```
execute immediate $$
BEGIN
  IF (
    NOT EXISTS(
      SELECT * 
      FROM "INFORMATION_SCHEMA"."COLUMNS"
      WHERE 
        "TABLE_CATALOG" = 'DB_NAME'
        AND "TABLE_SCHEMA" = 'SCHEMA_NAME'
        AND "TABLE_NAME" = 'TABLE_NAME' 
       AND "COLUMN_NAME" = 'col_name'
    )
  ) THEN
    ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS "DB_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME"."TABLE_NAME"
      ADD COLUMN "col_name" VARCHAR NULL;
  END IF;
END;
$$;
```