# Snowflake: DROP COLUMN if exists

Tags: t-sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I didn't find any easy way to "translate" the following T-SQL query in Snowflake.

```
ALTER TABLE table1
DROP COLUMN if exists [col1]
```

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Edit: Since writing this, Snowflake now supports adding a column if it does not exist or drop it if it exists.

[Snowflake conditional code: adding new column(idempotent script)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60459162/snowflake-conditional-code-adding-new-columnidempotent-script/77059232#77059232)

This is old code that was a workaround until this syntax was supported:

```
ALTER TABLE table1
drop column "col1";
```

If "col1" does not exist (wrapping in quotes makes it case sensitive), then it will result in a SQL compilation error. If generating an error won't work for your use case (for example code will think it's a more serious problem), you can use external logic (such as Python) or internal logic in a stored procedure to check for the column's existence before trying to drop it. You can test for a column's existence using this SQL, which will return 1 if the column exits, 0 if not:

```
select count(*) as COLUMN_EXISTS
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'SCHEMA_TO_CHECK' and
      TABLE_NAME   = 'TABLE_TO_CHECK' and
      COLUMN_NAME  = 'COLUMN_TO_CHECK'
;
```

Comment: It turns out that Snowflake actually supports both [ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77059232/5070879) and [DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77310790/5070879) though there is no explicit entry at: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table

Comment: Thank you, @LukaszSzozda. I have updated my answer to reflect the change.

Answer (score 2):

With introduction of [Snowflake Scripting and branching constructs](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/branch.html) ,such script is possible:

```
-- Snowsight
BEGIN
  IF (EXISTS(SELECT * 
                 FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
                 WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'TABLE1' 
                   AND TABLE_SCHEMA = 'PUBLIC'
                   AND COLUMN_NAME = 'COL1')) THEN
    ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS tab DROP COLUMN col1;
  END IF;
END;
```

Comment: Do you know if this is possible to run with snowsql? I can run it on dbeaver but in snowsql throws error if I run this and then another sql stmt on the same .sql file as I usually do :S

Comment: @neverMind Of course you could run it using SnowSQL. [Using Snowflake Scripting in SnowSQL and the Classic Console](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/developer-guide/snowflake-scripting/running-examples#passing-a-block-as-a-string-literal-to-execute-immediate)

Answer (score 0):

`DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS` is supported. Tested on version 7.37.1

```
SELECT CURRENT_VERSION();
-- 7.37.1

CREATE TABLE table1(col1 INT, col2 INT);
INSERT INTO table1(col1, col2) VALUES (1,10);

SELECT * FROM table1;
-- COL1 COL2
-- 1    10
```

Main query:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS table1 
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col1;
-- Statement executed successfully.

SELECT * FROM table1;
-- COL2
-- 10
```

Reapplying query on non-existing column:

```
ALTER TABLE IF EXISTS table1 
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS col1;
-- Statement executed successfully.
-- No error even though column does not exist
```

---

[ALTER TABLE - Table Column Actions](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/alter-table#table-column-actions-tablecolumnaction)

> ```
> DROP COLUMN [ IF EXISTS ] col_name [ CASCADE | RESTRICT ]
> ```
>
> Removes the specified column from the table.
>
> If you are not sure if the column already exists, you can specify `IF EXISTS` when dropping the column. If the column does not exist, `DROP COLUMN` has no effect and does not result in an error.