# Dynamic SQL in a Snowflake SQL Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, dynamic, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I would like to run a select query in a Snowflake SQL Stored Procedures (not Javascript) using dynamic SQL.  Is this possible?

What I am looking to do is pass in a database name as a parameter.  I then want to select all schema names from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA` for that database.  I would like to use the input parameter value for the database name to fully qualify the table.  For example, `DBNAME.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA`  where `DBNAME` is the name of my input parameter.

I would then like to loop through the results and for each schema do some code.

I find lots of Dynamic SQL examples for Javascript but I can't find one for a SQL stored procedure (language SQL) because it is so new.  Please let me know if this is possible and an example if possible.  Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An example of commenting schemas in a specific database:

Preparing setup:

```
CREATE DATABASE TEST3;
CREATE SCHEMA TEST1;
CREATE SCHEMA TEST2;

SELECT CATALOG_NAME, SCHEMA_NAME, COMMENT
FROM TEST3.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA;
```

[image]

Procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_proc(DB_NAME STRING)
RETURNS STRING
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
   TABLE_NAME   STRING;
   QUERY        STRING;
   OUTPUT       STRING DEFAULT '';
   c1           CURSOR FOR SELECT SCHEMA_NAME FROM TABLE(?) 
                WHERE SCHEMA_NAME != 'INFORMATION_SCHEMA';
BEGIN
   TABLE_NAME := CONCAT(DB_NAME, '.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.SCHEMATA');
   OPEN c1 USING (TABLE_NAME);

   FOR rec IN c1 DO
       QUERY := 'COMMENT ON SCHEMA ' || DB_NAME || '.' || rec.SCHEMA_NAME
                 || ' IS ''test_comment'';';
       OUTPUT := OUTPUT || QUERY;
       EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :QUERY;
   END FOR;
   
   RETURN :OUTPUT;
END;
$$;
```

Call:

```
CALL test_proc('TEST3');
```

Output:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!  This is exactly what I need!  It works great.

Comment: Would you be able to show me an example of using dynamic SQL to determine if a role exists?  For each schema in this code above, I need to create a role if it does not exist.  If it does, then I want to continue to the next schema.  Let me know if I should post this as a new question.

Comment: @LauraBeranek You could building query `CREATE ROLE IF NOT EXISTS name_of_schema..` inside the FOR loop . The query will not try to overwrite existing role. If your scenario is more roboust I suggest asking a more detailed question

Comment: Thank you!  Yes, I am already doing that.  But creating the role is just one of many things it needs to do.  If the role exists, then all of that has been done and I want to skip it altogether.  Some of the things I need to do will fail if tried more than once (ie granting future grants).  I will pose a new question.  Thank you!

Comment: @LauraBeranek Please find attached example of conditional statement in Snowflake Scripting: https://stackoverflow.com/a/70918783/5070879 It could be placed inside loop and multiple steps could be done using this pattern