# Issue While Creating Product of All Values Of Column (UDF in Snowflake)

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

I was trying to create a Snowflake SQL UDF
Where it computes the Values of the all values and will return the result to the user.

So firstly, i have tried the following approach

```
# The UDF that Returns the Result.

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION PRODUCT_OF_COL_VAL()
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
    SELECT EXP(SUM(LN(COL))) AS RESULT FROM SCHEMA.SAMPLE_TABLE
$$
```

The above code executes perfectly fine....
if you could see above (i have hardcoded the TABLE_NAME and COLUMN_VALUE) which is not i acutally want..

So, i have tried the following approach, by passing the column name dynamically..

```
create or replace function (COL VARCHAR)
RETURNS FLOAT
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
SELECT EXP(SUM(LN(COL))) AS RESULT from SCHEMA.SAMPLE_TABLE
$$
```

But it throws the following issue...

> Numeric Value 'Col' is not recognized

To elaborate more the Data type of the Column that i am passing is NUMBER(38,6)
and in the background its doing the following work..

> EXP(SUM(LN(TO_DOUBLE(COL))))

*Does anyone have any idea why this is running fine in Scenario 1 and not in Scenario 2 ?*

Comment: that is only possible with dynamic sql https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html

Comment: So SQL UDF Doesnt, helps us in solving this problem, thats what it implies isnt it

Comment: as far as i know, no database can do it, that one reason why dynamic sql exists

Comment: Now i got a solid understanding of the why its causing an issue. Thanks @nbk

Comment: sometimes it is hqrd to grasp, but basically at the start of a query, you must send a complete text and dyn sql delivers it to to the process

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully we will be able to have this kind of UDFs one day, in the meantime consider this answer using `ARRAY_AGG()` and a Python UDF:

Sample usage:

```sql
select count(*) how_many, multimy(array_agg(score)) multiplied, tags[0] tag
from stack_questions
where score > 0 
group by tag
limit 100
```

[image]

The UDF in Python - which also protects against numbers beyond `float`'s limits:

```sql
create or replace function multimy (x array)
returns float
language python
handler = 'x'
runtime_version = '3.8'
as
$$
import math
def x(x):
    res = math.prod(x)
    return res if math.log10(res)<308 else 'NaN'
$$
;
```

Comment: Thanks Felipe For the Sample UDF...It helps 

Answer (score 0):

The parameter you defined in SQL UDF will be evaluated as a literal:

When you call the function like PRODUCT_OF_COL_VAL('Col'), the SQL statement you execute becomes:

```
SELECT EXP(SUM(LN('Col'))) AS RESULT from SCHEMA.SAMPLE_TABLE
```

What you want to do is to generate a new SQL based on parameters, and it's only possible using "stored procedures". Check this one:

[Dynamic SQL in a Snowflake SQL Stored Procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052574/dynamic-sql-in-a-snowflake-sql-stored-procedure)

Comment: Thanks Atil For Your Valuable Insights... Seems like only Procedure is a way to Go....