# SELECT statement not working inside CONCAT

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to run the below query in snowflake

```
with table1 as 
(
    select
        schema_name,
        schema_owner,
        created,
        last_altered
    from 
        information_schema.schemata
), secondtable as
(
    select 
        schema_name as InternalName 
    from 
        table1
)
select * 
from concat('"ITCAPTURE".'(select * from secondtable),'."VW_SLA_KPI"')
```

I get an error:

> SQL compilation error: syntax error line 8 at position 20 unexpected '('. syntax error line 8 at position 78 unexpected ')'

What is wrong here?

Comment: Should there not be a "," after '"ITCAPTURE".' ? But beside, unless table1 contains exactly one row I don't see how this would work

Comment: looks like you're attempting to use a "variable" table name.  you can't do this without using dynamic SQL.  You'd need to use something like "Execute Immediate" https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/execute-immediate.html  Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052574/dynamic-sql-in-a-snowflake-sql-stored-procedure.  Now... using table literals may work. https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/literals-table.html  but that doesn't seem to be what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FROM clause requires table, view, table function or derived view. CONCAT is a scalar function so a proper way to construct a string is as follow:

```
with table1 as 
(
    select
        schema_name,
        schema_owner,
        created,
        last_altered
    from 
        information_schema.schemata
), secondtable as
(
    select 
        schema_name as InternalName 
    from 
        table1
)
select concat('"ITCAPTURE".',secondTable.InternalName ,'."VW_SLA_KPI"') 
from secondtable;
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. But I am not sure why he has used multiple CTEs when the same can be achieved with a simple query `select concat('"ITCAPTURE".', schema_name ,'."VW_SLA_KPI"') from information_schema.schemata`

Comment: @Mova That's is correct, CTE is not required at all. Most likely the code is just  simplified  case to be provided as sample for question and it is not the real code

Comment: Oww got you! Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys, yeah shouldn't have used unnecessary ctes

Answer (score 0):

Syntax:

```
CONCAT ( string_value1, string_value2 [, string_valueN ] )
```

Your string_values are not properly delimited with ',' character.

Comment: In addition, `(select * from secondtable)` is not your typical string_value

Comment: it still gives the same error