# Can we pass dynamic arguments to a SQL stored procedure in Snowflake

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am trying to build a framework to perform data validation on multiple tables using a stored procedure in Snowflake SQL.

Is there a way in which I can build a dynamic SQL query, which will be changed on the basis of input arguments.

Two checks need to be performed:

1. Not null check on defined columns
2. Uniqueness check on Primary key

I have created a reference table which will have entries of all the tables for which the data validation needs to be performed. It will have the below columns:
Database_Name, Schema_Name, Table_Name, Constraint_Type (Not_null, Primary key etc), Column_name( This column will have comma separated values of Primary keys and not null columns for each table)

The stored procedure will then dynamically create the SQL query based on the input parameters(Database_name, Schema_Name, Table_Name, Constraint_Type). The SQL will change for each of the table depending on the Columns which are defined in the Column_name of the reference table.
Simple SQL will look something like this for a not null constraint:

SELECT COUNT (*) FROM database_name.schema_name.table_name
WHERE <column_names> IS NULL.

I'm not sure how to use the column_names in the above SQL query which will change for every table.
Is there a better way to do this

Comment: You will stitch together your SQL String using concatenation, just like any string, and then use `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to run that sql string. See a similar question like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052574/dynamic-sql-in-a-snowflake-sql-stored-procedure. Know that this does open you up for a SQL injection attack if there is an untrustworthy person that has access to that table you have built, although that's likely not a big concern with the way you are building this.

Comment: As Snowflake enforces NOT NULL constraints, why are you bothering to check this?

Comment: @JNevill, Thanks for this. Is there any other way other than using a cursor to implement this.

Comment: @NickW, Yes Snowflake does enforce the NOT NULL constraints. However, we are loading the data into the staging layer using snowpipe and the idea is to load everything in stage and then do data validations, considering the performance in mind.

Comment: @vizqlshrivastava If you are only getting a single result row back from the SELECT statement of your table than you can use `INTO` to toss the column value into a variable, which you can then concatenate to your sql string in order to `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`.