# Snowflake create procedure to create function

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, user-defined-functions

Is possible in Snowflake to create a procedure that creates a function?

I want to obtain a similar situation, in order to pass dynamically the output returns list of the function as procedure's parameter:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE main_proc(input_param varchar)
RETURNS VARCHAR
LANGUAGE SQL
AS
$$
DECLARE
       res RESULTSET;
       query VARCHAR DEFAULT '
             CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION nest_funct()
             RETURNS TABLE (' || input_param || ')
             LANGUAGE SQL
             AS 
             $$
             BEGIN
                  SELECT *
                  FROM TABLE
             END;
             $$;

BEGIN
        res := (EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :query);
        RETURN TABLE (res);
END;
$$;
```

Comment: use dynamic sql https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71052574/dynamic-sql-in-a-snowflake-sql-stored-procedure

Comment: please edit your question with your try it so not readable

Comment: @nbk edited, but got error "unexpected BEGIN" for the first BEGIN (below SELECT * FROM TABLE)

Comment: after the first  $$; belongs  a single quote