# Snowflake Alter Statement Error ALTER TABLE ADD COLUMN

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

`ALTER TABLE Table_Name ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS Column_name dataType;`

The above Statement worked in Snowflake for a while, but now seeing error ProgrammingError: 000002 (0A000): Unsupported feature 'ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS'

Is it a test feature in Snowflake?

Comment: I'm not sure this worked, do you have a log/screenshot of it being sucessful?

Comment: Probably a duplicate. [Snowflake conditional code: adding new column(idempotent script)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77059232/5070879) - Yes it still works though it is not documented - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ljT5k.png (tested on Snowflake (AWS), v7.33.1)

Comment: Statement executed successfully in latest snoflake. I believe your table/column name or syntax may have some issues

Comment: Hi can you try changing the column  name and see if it adds the new column .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interestingly SQL Statement started working again. It didn't work for a while and only change that was happened is Snowflake applied a Behavior change. Reported to Snowflake Support about this. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC1eD.png)

[Working Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC1eD.png)